# How to unmarshal tag as string

Tags: java

I have xml which has value as .. It throwing exception while unmarshal using JAXB..
Error - javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:The element type "DB" must be terminated by the matching end-tag ""

xml string -

```
<Employee>
<source><DB></source>
</Employee>
```

P.S.- Here the DB is value, not tag

Any solution to handle it?

Comment: The problem is that the XML is not *well-formed*.  A conventional (spec compliant) XML parser won't handle it.  See the duplink for possible approaches to solving this.  (The best solution is to fix the XML ... or whatever produces it.)

Answer (score 3):

If `<DB>` is a value, then the String should look like

```xml
<Employee>
<source><![CDATA[<DB>]]></source>
</Employee>
```

or

```xml
<Employee>
<source>&lt;DB&gt;</source>
</Employee>
```